# Interface from DE1 board to PC in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, uart, hdl, intel-fpga

I am designing a simple IC tester using the DE1 altera board, and I really want to implement a simple user interface which a user can use to input variables into the VHDL program (e.g a small C++ app/form/yougetmypoint) so my basic idea is:

1) start FPGA (after programming)
2) FPGA launches app on PC screen asking for some simple info
3) user enters info, and it is implemented in the VHDL code.
4) from there it conducts some tests.

Basically I wanna know if this is even a possibility? At least if it is possible to implement this in a simple way perhaps using a UART? I've only been learning VHDL for a few days, so please be patient if this is dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't get the idea of FPGA and VHDL.

You cannot implement in VHDL any user interface, that will show up in PC. VHDL is not programming language, but hardware description language. What you write in VHDL is code, that describes what FPGA does. You specify functions, and then some tool translates (synthesizes) it to digital electronic circuit. In this circuit all kind of FPGA's stuff is used - LUT tables, registers, buffers, etc. When you launch FPGA and program it, you send it bitstream file, with instruction how all this elements has to be connected to do what you specify in VHDL. It has nothing to do with program, that you can launch on PC.

To do what you want, you can implement UART interface in FPGA, and connect it to PC using some USB to UART converter. Then you can write some app in whatever programming, or scripting language you prefer (for example C++, or Python). In this program you can get some input from user, and send it via UART to FPGA.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! ya I am pretty lost, but your answer really helps!  I will look into how to interface an app with a UART then! do you have suggestions on where I can find tips for this?

Comment: Well... VHDL is sort-of a programming language. With some effort you could develop some sort of application. It will not compile to an executable that can be run on an OS, but you could for instance use VHDL to solve some [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problems. Furthermore, it is possible to implement a soft-core microcontroller on the FPGA, which can run applications. In this case, you could for instance have the FPGA connect up to the PC via USB as a mass storage device, containing an `autorun.inf`, which would launch an application on the PC...

Comment: Well, yes, surely it can be used as programming language, for example for simulation. But it's main purpose is to be used for synthesis digital circuits, and I didn't wanted to go much into details, so I wrote it this way for simplicity.

Comment: @D.P. I would use Google. First, search for how UART works, then pick some programming language, and search how to use UART in it, then find some VHDL block with UART, and use it.